# Is the set of matrix with bounded entries are compact set?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, analysis, compactness

Let $A$ be the set of square matrix with entries $a_{ij}\in [a,b]$ where $a,b$ is real number. Is $A$ a compact set?

$A$ is bounded set with given a norm however i don't know how to prove the closeness of $A$. Are there any "matrix version sandwich theorem" so that can prove the limit of the given matrix sequence is contains in in $A$?  Thank you for any help.

Comment: First of all, in general metric spaces, compact is not equivalent to "closed and bounded". Instead, you need "closed and totally bounded", a stronger condition. For example, $$d(x,y) = \begin{cases} |x - y| & |x - y| < 1\\1 & |x - y| \ge 1\end{cases}$$ defines a metric on $\Bbb R$ that produces the same topology as the normal one. But every set is bounded under it. Yet $[0,\infty)$, though closed and bounded, is still not compact.  So you cannot just say "given a norm" if want to use boundedness to prove the set is compact. You have to be more specific about the norm.

Comment: That said, the set of $m \times m$ matrices is easily identifiable with $\Bbb R^{m^2}$, where $A = [a,b]^{m^2}$ and is compact as the product of a finite number of compact sets. But that presumes you have the same topology on the set of matrices as on $\Bbb R^{m^2}$.